# How do I change the background color in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I have a script that renders graphs in gnuplot. The graphs all end up with an ugly white background. How do I change this? (Ideally, with a command that goes into a gnuplot script, as opposed to a command-line option or something in a settings file)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ooh, found it. It's along the lines of:

```
set terminal png x222222 xffffff
```

Comment: I get `obsolete color option`.

Answer (score 23):

You can change the background color by command `set object 1 rectangle from screen 0,0 to screen 1,1 fillcolor rgb"green" behind` to set the background color to the  the color you specified (here is green).

To get more knowledge about setting the background in gnuplot, you can visit this [blog](http://gnuplot-surprising.blogspot.com/). There are even provided methods to set a gradient color background and background pictures. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

It is a setting for some terminal (windows use background).  Check out colorbox including its bdefault.

/Allan

Comment: But... a `colorbox` shows the "color legend" in case of a 3D plot; what does it have to do with overall background color?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [official documentation](http://www.gnuplot.info/documentation.html), as of version 5.4 the right way to set the background color in a gnuplot script is something like the following:

```
set term wxt background rgb "gray75"
```

Note that the color must be quoted. Beside color names you can use hex values with the format "#AARRGGBB" or "0xAARRGGBB