# GNUPlot color inversion

Tags: gnuplot, background-color, color-scheme

Since my eyes get less strained with dark windows, I'd like to set a dark background in my gnuplot terminal. [Setting a dark square beneath the plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69480/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-in-gnuplot) would be a solution, if only this would not affect readability (dark lines on dark background...).

I don't want to spend my day in finding color combinations, however by inverting the terminal color I would get exactly what I need: dark background and readable plots.

Does anyone know a command for inverting the terminal, or the name of an interactive terminal (supported by GNU/Linux) which supports color inversion?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many terminals (including `png` and `wxt`) have `background` option.

You can set dark background, for example:

```
set terminal wxt background '#00222222'
```

And then change border/axis color to something light, for example:

```
set style line 101 lc rgb '#808080' lt 1 lw 1
set border 3 front ls 101
```

I don't know about automatic 'color inversion', but this seems like a pretty good workaround. You can find some interesting information in [Ease your plotting with config-snippets](http://www.gnuplotting.org/ease-your-plotting-with-config-snippets/) article.

See [gnuplot-colorbrewer](https://github.com/aschn/gnuplot-colorbrewer) for some predefined color schemes.

Comment: This is not exactly what I was searching for, still probably it simply cannot be done. I'm accepting the answer since it represents a good enough approximation of my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

This has been something I've tried to do for a little while now, hence the answer. If you are okay with its other limitations (not looking at highly formatted output files for instance) and are using the X display server, the `x11` terminal is capable of straight-up inverting terminal colours via the .Xdefaults/.Xresources file. Testing in Ubuntu 22.04, gnuplot v5.4, I set my `~/.Xdefaults` file to contain the line

```
Gnuplot*reverseVideo: true
```

and added the line

```
xrdb ~/.Xdefaults
```

to the end of my /home/.bashrc file. (For those that need this info, `.bashrc` file is executed everytime a new terminal/console window is opened, and `xrdb <inputfile>` looks at `<inputfile>` to customize display properties for all programs that use the X server for display. In our case, we tell X server to invert `gnuplot` colours if it is using the `x11` terminal for display.)
Plotting usually with

```
set term x11
plot sin(x)/x w l ls 7 lw 2
... #further plot instructions here if needed
```

brings up something like the what I've attached in the links below. I will show both cases, with and without the `gnuplot*reverseVideo` edit in `.Xdefaults`. Don't have enough reputation to embed images.

[Without *reverseVideo (default `x11` terminal behavior)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POk9m.png)

[With *reverseVideo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEnrz.png)