# Gnuplot: default background color terminal "qt"

Tags: qt, colors, gnuplot

I'm using gnuplot 5.0 with term `qt - Qt terminal`. Now, when I `plot` (or `splot`) whatever I want I have always to follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69480/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-in-gnuplot) command

```
set object 1 rectangle from screen 0,0 to screen 1,1 fillcolor rgb "white" behind
```

to set the background color to white. In fact, as default background color I have "black", so anytime I plot something, e.g.

```
set term qt
set pm3d
splot sin(x*y)
```

the output window has a black background, as below

[image: QT_BLACK]

Now, if i export the plot, it shows correctly the white background,

[image: PLOT]

Since having an interactive term (such as `qt`) but can't interact with it is really annoying, the only possible way is to set manually the background color with the command `set object` or with the "Terminal configuration" tool, which anyway does not allow to change the color definitely

[image: Term config]

I've looked around, but nobody seems to know whether there's a command to change definitely the background color in `qt` terminal, so anytime I plot with tis term I have to change it manually.

Hope someone knows the solution!
Thx!

Comment: Create file `~/.gnuplot` and add there what you want to be in preamble.

Answer (score 0):

When you save a graph

```sh
gnuplot > save "test.plt"
```

and you open it, you will see that the file contains ALL the value for all the possible option for your graph.
Those information are the default of your graph and gnuplot under linux reads them in an hidden configuration file locate in the home and called `.gnuplot`

I suggest you to import to read [this](http://labs.guidolin.net/2010/03/how-to-create-beautiful-gnuplot-graphs.html) it gives you a nice one to use.
Using the above one as a model I created my personal one which is available [here](https://github.com/cippo1987/gnuplotConfig)